# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to include User Details and roles in in Login response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have this code:

Models:

```
public class AuthResult
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

public class JwtTokenManager : IJwtTokenManager
{
    private readonly JwtSettings _jwtSettings;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly TokenValidationParameters _tokenValidationParameters;
    public async Task<AuthResult> GenerateClaimsTokenAsync(string username, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {

                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()), // TODO: encrypt user id for added security
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),

            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_jwtSettings.Expiration),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var refreshTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()), // TODO: encrypt user id for added security
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, _jwtSettings.Issuer),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),

            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_jwtSettings.Expiration),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        // Create JWT tokens
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var refreshtoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(refreshTokenDescriptor);

        return new AuthResult
        {
            AccessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
            TokenType = "Bearer",
            ExpiresIn = _jwtSettings.Expiration.Seconds,
            RefreshToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(refreshtoken)
        };
    }
}
```

Identity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, finally I have **SignInCommandHandler**

```
public class SignInCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<SignInCommand, AuthResult>
{
    private readonly ISignInManager _signInManager;
    private readonly IJwtTokenManager _jwtTokenManager;

    public SignInCommandHandler(ISignInManager signInManager, IJwtTokenManager jwtTokenManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _jwtTokenManager = jwtTokenManager;
    }
    public async Task<AuthResult> Handle(SignInCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // validate username & password 
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(request.Username, request.Password, false, false);

        // Throw exception if credential validation failed
        if (!result.Successful)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        // Generate JWT token response if validation successful
        AuthResult response = await _jwtTokenManager.GenerateClaimsTokenAsync(request.Username, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I have done something like:

var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

in **JwtTokenManager**

How do I involve the detail of the logged in user and his roles in the

> **return response**?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible and usual practice to embed roles and such info in the returned JWT token itself.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran - How do I embed that in the code I have above?